# Need help changing back the correct wordpress url

Tags: urls, localhost, linux

Hello I've just recently installed wordpress today on a development linux server. Everything seemed ok until when I stupidly changed the wordpress url. Initailly it was just http://localhost/ but I changed that to http://localhost/wordpress in the settings area. Now I cannot seem to login again, because everytime I login, it takes me to a page 404 error. So is there another way to change the wordpress url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the steps outlined here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Specifically did you copy the .htaccess and index.php files back to the root and edit the index.php file with correct filepaths as stated in points 7 - 9?

**Update**

The problem was solved by modifying these two options in the wp_options table:

- `siteurl`
- `home`

(See comments)

Comment: Ah I see, but I don't really want to change my wordpress url or move my wordpress folder into a new directory. All I really want to do is change the wordpress url back to `http://localhost/`

Comment: If what you are saying is that all you did was change the "WordPress address (URL)" on the General settings page to "http://localhost/wordpress", then I think you will need to edit the setting in the database directly. Is that your situation?

Comment: Yes - as I said I can't seem to change it through wordpress's admin settings. So if its from the database (I use MySQL) which table does it store the URL from?

Comment: You need to look in wp_options. There's two options: "siteurl" and "home". The first is the setting for "'WordPress address (URL)" and latter for "'Site address (URL)" which is a little counter intuitive, but see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: I guess if you set them both to "http://localhost" that should do the trick. If that doesn't work take a look at this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL   You can also define these in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: ok that seem to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

for me i used MAMP. I went to the table in MyPHPAdmin and edited the data on the place noted. Worked for me! Big lifesaver